# What tools may one use to disprove uniform convergence?

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

Ok, this is perhaps a very general question but here goes:

**Question:** What tools (theorems) may one use to prove or disprove uniform convergence?
I am aware of only $2$.

1. The thoerem that if the limit function is not continuous , then the convergence is not   uniform.
2. The thoerem with $\lim \sup |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$.

What other thoerms are out there for someone to use in order to prove that a sequence of functions converge or does not converge uniformly to a function $f$.

Comment: uniform convergence implies convergence of the respective integrals, so the contrapositive gives a way to show a sequence does not converge uniformly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: This is the first time I hear something like that... Does there exist a theorem that discusses convergence on an unbounded interval e.g $(0, +\infty)$? or intervals of this form...