# Uniform convergence of a function involving $\ln $.

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Continuing the question from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158052/what-tools-may-one-use-to-disprove-uniform-convergence) I would like to know how to examine the uniform convergence of $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{\ln (nx)}{n+n^4 x}, \; n \in \mathbb{N}, \; x \in (0, +\infty)$ to the $0$ function. All of the thoerems I know , fail. Definition is useless, that $\lim \sup $ test requires me to find a subsequence $a_{k_n}$ such that $\lim \sup |a_{k_n}-0| \neq 0$ which I find pretty difficult.

Therefore I don't have alternatives to attack this monster. Intuitively I know that it does not converge to the zero function uniformly but I don't have the tools to prove it.

I really need some help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $0 < n^3x < 1$,

$$\left|\frac{\ln(nx)}{n+ n^4x}\right|= \frac{-\ln(nx)}{n(1+ n^3x)}> \frac{-\ln(nx)}{2n}.$$

With $x_n = e^{-n}$ we have $n^3x_n < 1$ for $n$ sufficiently large, and

$$|f_n(x_n)|=\left|\frac{\ln(nx_n)}{n+ n^4x_n}\right|> \frac{-\ln(ne^{-n})}{2n}=\frac{n-\ln n }{2n}=\frac1{2}-\frac{\ln n }{2n}> \frac1{4}.$$

The last inequality is true for $n$ sufficiently large since $\ln n/n\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Therefore,

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x_n)| > 0,$$

and the sequence fails to converge uniformly to $0$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Hmm... I think you have a typo.. somewhere.. the denominator should be $n+n^4 x$.. no?

Comment: @Tolaso - thanks I corrected.  The argument is still the same.

Comment: Yeah.. I noticed that... Thank you.. May I ask you something? I have a conjecture, perhaps it is silly.. but do you believe that every function $f_n$ containing a log , DOES NOT converge uniformly to a limit function?

Comment: The same proof works for functions of the same kind , say $\displaystyle \frac{\ln(nx)}{n+n^4x^3}$, or $\displaystyle \displaystyle \frac{\ln(nx)}{n+n^4x^5}$ right?

Comment: Yes -- you just need a sequence $x_n \to 0$ where say $n^3x^3< 1$ and $\ln(nx_n)/n$ does not go to $0$  - reciprocal exponential works again.

Comment: Good.. all I need to do know... is to find a lower bound for for the quantity.. Let's say , about the $f_n=-\dfrac{\ln(nx)}{n+n^4x^3}$ how would you bound it from below?

Comment: On your conjecture, do you mean for any domain?  This sequence converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$ with $a > 0$.

Comment: No, I mean in the domain $(0, +\infty)$.

Comment: OK - I have to think about that.  Regarding your other question, if $n^3x^3 < 1$ then $f_n = -\ln(nx)/(n(1 + n^3x^3)) > -\ln(nx)/2n$.  We can use $x_n = e^{-n}$ again since $e^{-3n}n^3 < 1$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Take your time... if you find any results post it as answer As for the other question I found the same bound but I was unsure.